# Get height of virtual keyboard in browser in Windows 8 Metro mode

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro, internet-explorer-10, virtual-keyboard

I have an issue when using Internet Explorer 10 on a Windows 8 tablet in Metro mode. When visible the keyboard overlaps a part of the browser its content. In order to provide a good user experience I need to resize that content. And to do that I need the remaining height of the browser. Can someone point me in the right direction how to get the height of the virtual keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get height of virtual keyboard in browser, but on IE 10 metro mode, you can use onresize event to get the available height (window.innerHeight) after the virtual keyboard is visible.

You can use the old height (when keyboard is non-visible) - new height (when keyboard is visible) to get the  virtual keyboard height if you really need this.

remember, onresize event will not be fired if IE is in desktop mode when virtual keyboard is displayed.